# How to get Character from one file to another? (newbie)

Tags: export, scene

So I downloaded a character and it came in a .blend file with different clothes, hairs, etc.but now I want to put it into a room, I downloaded (also.blend). So my question is, how do I take all the things I need from one scene and put it into another without destroying the folder structure and with the rig still working? I tried to export the Character and its rig as a .fbx file, but it just removed all the bones, so I can't pose it now. Is there any simple solution to my problem?

I have only a few hours of experience with blender so it would be great if you could keep it as beginner friendly as possible ;)

Comment: Open 2 "copies" of blender (run 2 instances of the same program) - in one program open the .blend file with your scene, and in the other one open the .blend file with your character. Select all the necessary parts of your character (mesh, skeleton, etc...) then copy (Ctrl+C) from the one file and paste (Ctrl+V) into the file with your scene.

Comment: Or you can use the Append function but it will be more tedious if you have a lot of objects